# Wordpress causing slow 301 redirects

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a WordPress site and many of the `/page/` links on my site show up as a 301 redirect. That wouldn't be an issue except that it's adding almost **three seconds** of load time to the page for no apparent reason.

Comment: Try to find what part of the request is slower. Is it the webserver accepting the connection, the webdaemon generating the 301, wordpress generating the page contents, your browser doing the redirect? Firebug might be helpful.

Comment: 123ms to connect, 71ms for SSL, 2.7s waiting, 1ms receiving.

Comment: are you using manual .htaccess to do the redirect or some fancy wordpress plugin?

Comment: +1 to @themerlinproject.  I hope you are using .htaccess for the redirect. Apache redirects are much more faster than PHP redirects.